# $elemMatch with distinct

Tags: mongodb, distinct

I have some problems with distinct queries.

```
db.sessions.distinct("tests.device_serial")
[
        "",
        "5b34f4bf9854a",
        "5b34f4bf98664",
        "5b34f4bf98712",
        "5b34f4bf9876b",
        "5b34f4bf987c6"
]
```

I don't want to get the result with empty strings. I tried to run query:

```
 db.sessions.distinct("tests.device_serial", {"tests.device_serial" : {$ne: ""}})
[ ]
```

Why I got empty array? Where is my mistake?

Comment: this shoud work db.sessions.distinct('{"tests.device_serial":{$ne: ""}}');

Comment: db.sessions.distinct('{"tests.device_serial":{$ne: ""}}')
[ ]

Same problem. MongoDB shell version v3.6.3.

Comment: Is `tests.device_serial` an array?

Comment: it would be better if you post your sample data because from here it seems to be ok

Comment: @anthony-winzlet looks like this [{
    "obj_lens_inspection_mask": 6,
    "tests": [{
        "device_serial": "5acccdf25c089",
        "firmware_version": "3.1.00.121"
    }]
}, {
    "obj_lens_inspection_mask": 3,
    "tests": [{
        "device_serial": "5acccdf25c57a",
        "firmware_version": "3.1.00.121"
    }, {
        "device_serial": "",
        "firmware_version": ""
    }, {
        "device_serial": "5acccdf25c5de",
        "firmware_version": "3.1.00.121"
    }]
}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing tests.device_serial is an array, here's your mistake :

```
 db.sessions.distinct("tests.device_serial", {"tests.device_serial" : {$ne: ""}})
```

Query in your distinct command is filtering documents where the array 'tests' **contains** a field named device_serial with a value of "", and not only the fields in array.

To achieve what you want, you can use aggregation framework, unwind array to multiple documents, filter and group by null with an $addToSet command to get distinct values.

Here's the query :

```
db.sessions.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$tests"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
            "tests.device_serial":{$ne:""}
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
              "_id":null,
                "device_serials":{$addToSet:"$tests.device_serial"}
            }
        },
    ]
);
```